# SCP is creating subdirectory... but I just want it to copy directly

Tags: scp

I'm trying to use scp to copy recursively from a local directory to a remote directory....  I have created the folders on the remote side:

Remote Location (already created):

```
/usr/local/www/foosite
```

I am running scp from the local machine in directory:

/usr/local/web/www/foosite

But it's copying the "foosite" directory as a subdirectory...  I just want the contents of the folder, not the folder itself...

Here is the command I'm using:

```
scp -r /usr/local/web/www/foosite scpuser@216.99.999.99:/usr/local/www/foosite
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that if you don't use the asterisk (*) in the local part of the call, scp will create a new top level directory in the remote server.  It should look like this:

```
scp -r /usr/local/web/www/foosite/* scpuser@216.99.999.99:/usr/local/www/foosite
```

This says "Copy the CONTENTS" (but not the directory itself) to the remote location.

Hope this helps...  Took me an hour or so to figure this out!!!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I think there is a better answer. The trick is to leave the foosite directory off of the destination:

```
scp -r /usr/local/web/www/foosite scpuser@216.99.999.99:/usr/local/www
```

This will create the foosite directory on the destination if it does not exist, but will just copy files into foosite if the directory already exists. Basically the -r option will copy the last directory in the path and anything under it. If that last directory already exists on the destination, it just doesn't do the mkdir.

Comment: That only works if you want the directories to have the same name

Comment: Yes, but the question asked specified that the same directory name was desired. This is just a nice wrinkle that allows you to not care if the directory already exists on the destination. I don't think there's an easy way to get scp to create a directory of a different name, though. It has to already exist.